# Unity - Slow Down all Element when they enter a specific Area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I want to develop a game (2D), in which you can place "Time Bubbles", in which every Object which is inside slows down its movement.

In the Script for the "Time Bubble" I tried the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeBubble : MonoBehaviour {
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    GameObject temp = GameObject.Find(other.name);

    temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
    temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = Vector3.right * 0;

    }

}
```

Which is not Working.

Does someone knows how to slow down all Elements inside the bubble?

Comment: "is not working" is not a problem statement. You need to state what happened and what you expected

Answer (score 0):

Observation!

- If you have another script altering the velocity, like a charachter controller, you CANNOT set the speed from this script, you will need to pass the speedReductionFactor to your Charachter controller, and update the velocity there using it and the Input logic, i'll leave that to you.

  ```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  public class TimeBubble : MonoBehaviour {

      [Range(0,1)]
      public float speedReductionFactor = .5f;

      List <GameObject> objectsInside;

      Rigidbody2D rb;

      void Start ()
      {
          objectsInside = new List<GameObject>();
      }

      void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
          rb = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
          if (rb == null)
              return;
          rb.velocity *= speedReductionFactor;
          objectsInside.Add(other.gameObject);
      }

      void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D other){
          rb = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
          if (rb != null && objectsInside.Contains(other.gameObject)) {
              rb.velocity *= (1 / speedReductionFactor);
              objectsInside.Remove(other.gameObject);
          }
      }

  }
  ```